# PHP IMAP Plain text one jarbled paragraph

Tags: php, text, imap, plaintext

I'm using `imap` from php and retrieving a message. The contents can either be html or plain text. When html is available, I resort to using the html contents for displaying. However, if html text is not available, than I must use the plain text for rendering messages to the user.

**My question is, when I display the plain text, it comes as one jarbled paragraph. I'd like to figure out how to format the plain text into a viewable fashion. This could just be a multipart issue, and the parts together form one jarbled paragraph. If so, what should I do? Erase the parts that are not the most recent? Is there a way to format the plain text regalrdess**

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `nl2br` or `<pre>` on the plain text?

Comment: No I have not. That might be the answer I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can enclose the text in `<pre>` tags to preserve the formatting

You can also use [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to insert `<br />` before all new lines